# Reading XML into Dataset with correct schema

Tags: c#

I have some xml like this.

```
<RootTop>

<FileTablets>
<Tablet Name="">
</Tablet>
</FileTablets>

<DirectoryTablets>
  <Directory FullPath="Path1" Id="" />    
<Directory FullPath="Path2" Id="" />
     <SubPath Path="Path Id="" />
     <SubPath Path="Path Id="" />
     <SubPath Path="Path Id="" />
  </Directory>
</DirectoryTablets>
</RootTop>
```

When I user dataset.readxml() with inferring schema or read schema, data gets read into the data set but not in the format I want. I want only the information under DirectoryTablets Sub tree. How can I read the data directly into dataset in the format I want 
Here is the format I want:
Table name: DirectoryTablets

FullPath Id SubPath-Path SubPath-Id (Empty if subpath nodes don’t exist)

FullPath Id SubPath-Path SubPath-Id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `DataSet` class is an in-memory representation of a relational data model.

Not all XML maps to a relational data model.

This means that some XML can't be read into a `DataSet`.

This includes the XML you posted.

Choose a different mechanism for processing the XML.

Comment: Thanks for the response John. Could you tell me a little more about why this xml cant be read into a dataset. Or please point me to a link, if you can.

Comment: Is the altenative approach to read the xml by nodes and write to a dataset appropriate? Thanks again.

Comment: I just told you. See [Relational model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_model) and [XML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xml). There are kinds of XML that don't map to a relational model. Those can't be read into a DataSet, which is a representation of a relational model. It's all pretty simple - apples aren't oranges, though they are both fruits.

Comment: What version of .NET are you using? If you're up to date, then use LINQ to XML, which makes processing XML very easy. If you're stuck at .NET 2.0, then I recommend using XmlDocument.

Comment: I am using 4.0. I will try Linq to XML. Thanks.